# HTML - How to hide hyperlink after click?

Tags: html

I have a simple HTML hyperlink as below:

```
<div style="text-align:left">
<a href="https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer" >Enable Flash</a>

<a href="https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer" ><img border="0" alt="Enable Flash" src="enable_flash.gif"/></a>


</div>
```

When I click on it, it prompts and ask if I want to allow Adobe Flash so if I clicked on Allow then it shall load the documents in the viewer. The problem is the hyperlinks are still visible and is bothering the top border of my window. See below screenshot for example.

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a way to get rid of this?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: You do realise that [even adobe](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/07/with-html5-webgl-javascript-ascendant-adobe-to-cease-flash-dev-at-end-of-2020/) plan to end flash support soon.

Comment: Yes by 2020 I believed.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `click` listener to the `a` element.

```
<a href="https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer" onClick="this.style='display: none';">Enable Flash</a>
```

Comment: It doesn't go away on click.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but it does work. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/xkar81n3/